# Need help with using regular expression in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match pattern like '@(a-zA-Z0-9)+ " but not like 'abc@test'.

So this is what I tried:

```
Pattern MY_PATTERN
    = Pattern.compile("\\s@(\\w)+\\s?"); 
String data = "abc@gere.com #gogasig @jytaz @tibuage";
    Matcher m = MY_PATTERN.matcher(data);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
boolean result = m.find(); 
while(result) {
    System.out.println (" group " + m.group());
    result = m.find();
}
```

But I can only see '@jytaz', but not @tibuage.
How can I fix my problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This pattern should work: `\B(@\w+)`

The `\B` scans for non-word boundary in the front. The `\w+` already excludes the trailing space. Further I've also shifted the parentheses so that the `@` and `+` comes in the correct group. You should preferably use `m.group(1)` to get it.

Here's the rewrite:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\B(@\\w+)");
String data = "abc@gere.com #gogasig @jytaz @tibuage";
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(data);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(" group " + m.group(1));
}
```